# How to stop J2SSH SFTP put command from changing permissions

Tags: java, sftp, chmod, j2ssh

I get the error:

```
java.io.IOException: This server does not support operations to modify file attributes.
at com.sshtools.j2ssh.sftp.SftpSubsystemClient.getOKRequestStatus(Unknown Source)
at com.sshtools.j2ssh.sftp.SftpSubsystemClient.setAttributes(Unknown Source)
at com.sshtools.j2ssh.sftp.SftpSubsystemClient.changePermissions(Unknown Source)
at com.sshtools.j2ssh.SftpClient.chmod(Unknown Source)
at com.sshtools.j2ssh.SftpClient.put(Unknown Source)
at com.sshtools.j2ssh.SftpClient.put(Unknown Source)
at com.sshtools.j2ssh.SftpClient.put(Unknown Source)
at com.sshtools.j2ssh.SftpClient.put(Unknown Source)
```

After some digging I found out that the SftpClient.put command does an automatic chmod after it uploads a file. Is there a way for me to disable this?

I know for sure the initial .put works as expected because when I check the remote server for the file, it is present and all bytes accounted for.

Comment: There's possibly no solution. See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803245/sshtools-sftpclient-put-failing-with-no-such-file

Comment: I've seen this thread. I assumed his problem was just as he stated, where his files are being removed shortly after a successful upload. Though the common issue of a chmod after upload is still evident. I really hope there is some sort of work around someone knows about.

Comment: Issue resolved using Jsch library instead.

Comment: Please post the resolution as an answer and accept it to close this question. Also consider upvoting my answer to the other question that suggests this solution :)